# How to drag a listboxitem in WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

As the codes below, I have a listboxitem.
I want to drag the listboxitem horizontally to right and disappear.
but when drag it, this error pops up,

transform.X += e.HorizontalChange;**[NullReferenceException]**

I check the Watch, found that the e.HorizontalChange has a value of 65.0, why it shows error? and How I accomplish my goal?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TasksListDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Margin="0,0,0,10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener 
                    DragDelta="taskitem_DragDelta"
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="432" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        </TextBlock>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="due:" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DueDate}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and the code behind file is

```
    private void taskitem_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        TranslateTransform transform = (sender as StackPanel).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        transform.X += e.HorizontalChange;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your StackPanel does not have a `TranslateTransform` specified, so the .RenderTransform property is null when cast to `TranslateTransform`.

The reason is that an element can have a number of different types of transforms (`CompositeTransform`, `ScaleTransform`, `SkewTransform`, `TranslateTransform`, `RotateTransform` etc). By default an element has no `RenderTransform` at all.

If you use Blend to edit XAML a `CompositeTransform` is the most common type it creates (as it encompasses many different types of transforms in one object).

Add a default `TranslateTransform` to the declaration of the `StackPanel` and it should work.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Margin="0,0,0,10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
```

*As a side note: you should always test the result of "as" operations as they can be null.*